# XPath floating point division?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to use XPath functions to search for elements containing fractions whose decimal value is below a certain value.  Obviously, I could just get all elements and process it afterwards but I would like to know if it can be done directly with XPath.

Assuming I have the HTML below, I would like to return elements whose decimal value is less than or equal to 0.1, so the element containing 1/10 would only be returned.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>1/8</div>
    <div>1/10</div>
    <div>1/5</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression,

```
//div[    number(substring-before(., '/')) 
      div number(substring-after (., '/')) <= 0.1]
```

will select

```
<div>1/10</div>
```

as requested.

Comment: Thank you that worked, can I ask what "div" in the middle means, I'm assuming it means divide but I don't see it mentioned in the documentation - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp

Comment: Correct.  Per the [***real*** documentation, W3C XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/): [***The div operator performs floating-point division according to IEEE 754.***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers)